# Recordset close and set to nothing one-liner

Tags: vba, syntax, vbscript, ado

I remember there was a shorthand syntax that was commonly used to close the recordset and set it to nothing in one line it used a syntax like

rst.Close := Nothing

But cannot remember the right syntax, anybody out there with a better memory than mine? Google couldn't help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be this?

```
 rst.Close : set rst = nothing
```

HTH

Comment: Just as additional info. You can use ":" to Join many lines of code into one single line.

Comment: For most purposes I think joining lines is abomination, but I s'pose I can see this as an acceptable exception.